# Anime where characters use gems to enlarge their pets to fight

Tags: story-identification, anime

Looking for an anime that was aired in India in 2016. In it characters use gems to enlarge their pets like animals to fight. The main character has a god creature named Eit and at the climax the queen turns out to be the main villain.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? Using gems and enlarging creatures to fight is quite a common trope in anime. For example, why they fight? Any of the story lines/plot? What do they do in the episodes? Do they fight and defeat the queen? If you remember anything else please [edit] your question to include those details.